# Функция fwrite php

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, на HTML странице есть две select формы, у них заданы имена. Нужно чтобы фаил-обработчик php взял эти два значения и записал в файл. У самого получается записать только одно значение.
Вот то, что у меня получилось в html и php коде:

```html
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
 <select name="doc">
    <option value="fr">Док1</option>
    <option value="bs">Док2</option>
    <option value="mel">Док3</option>
    <option value="gl">Док4</option>
</select>
    <select name="doc1">
        <option value="fr1">Док1</option>
        <option value="bs1">Док2</option>
        <option value="mel1">Док3</option>
        <option value="gl1">Док4</option>
    </select>
<p><input type="submit" name=submit value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

```php
<?php
$filename = 'test.txt';
$somecontent = $_POST['doc'];

if (is_writable($filename)) {


if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
     echo "Не могу открыть файл ($filename)";
     exit;
}

if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
    echo "Не могу произвести запись в файл ($filename)";
    exit;
}

echo "Ура! Записали ($somecontent) в файл ($filename)";

fclose($handle);

} else {
echo "Файл $filename недоступен для записи";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если заменить

```
$somecontent = $_POST['doc'];
```

на код

```
$somecontent = $_POST['doc']."\t".$_POST['doc1'];
```

то оба значения запишутся в файл через знак табуляции.

Answer (score 1):

вы принимаете лишь `$somecontent = $_POST['doc'];` попробуйте добавить переменую которая берет значение `$_POST['doc1']` или же попробуйте заменить на это `$somecontent = $_POST;`